# Get values from Select statement and Insert them in Temp table Stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

Here it is my stored procedure.

Here i want to select data from a table save it in a variable then insert in other variable.But here my select statement has where. In it the value for the day should come from the for loop. Means in for loop i will get DAYNAME(dateTime) for a particular day. On the basis of that i want to fetch values and use it in a insert statement.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS home_cleaner.getAvailableDateAndTime;

CREATE PROCEDURE home_cleaner.`getAvailableDateAndTime`(dateTime date)
  BEGIN
  DECLARE dateTime               datetime DEFAULT NOW();
  DECLARE dateTimeCounter        int DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE dateTimeCounterLimit   int DEFAULT 90;
  DECLARE result                 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
  DECLARE result1                varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
  DECLARE result2                varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
  DECLARE result3                varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
  DECLARE result4                varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;

  DECLARE
     c CURSOR FOR SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                            cleaner_calender.from,
                            "-",
                            cleaner_calender.to)
                            AS result
                    FROM cleaner_calender
                   WHERE day = DAYNAME(dateTime) AND status = "1";



  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
  CREATE TABLE foo
  (
     id         int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     date1      date NULL,
     dayNameP   varchar(20) NULL,
     timings    varchar(255) NULL
  )
  ENGINE = innodb;

OPEN c;
  WHILE dateTimeCounter < dateTimeCounterLimit
  DO
     // here i want to fetch result1 for the dateTime which will be incrementing
     FETCH c INTO result1;

     INSERT INTO foo(date1, dayNameP, timings)
     VALUES (dateTime, DAYNAME(dateTime), result1);

     SET dateTime = DATE_ADD(dateTime, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
     SET dateTimeCounter = dateTimeCounter + 1;
  END WHILE;    
 CLOSE c;
 SELECT * FROM foo;
END;
```